# PDF to Bytearray conversion in java

Tags: java, pdf, arrays, inputstream

Below is my code to convert a PDF file to byte array

```
public class ByteArrayExample{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter File name: ");
        String str = bf.readLine();
        File file = new File(str); 
        //File length
        int size = (int)file.length(); 
        if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            System.out.println("File is to larger");
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size]; 
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)); 
        int read = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (read < bytes.length && (numRead=dis.read(bytes, read,
                bytes.length-read)) >= 0) {
            read = read + numRead;
        }
        System.out.println("File size: " + read);
        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (read < bytes.length) {
            System.out.println("Could not completely read: "+file.getName());
        }
    }
  catch (Exception e){
  e.getMessage();
  }
  }
}
```

Issue is this actually converts the file name into the byte array not the actual PDF file.Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What do you want to do with the PDF file?  If you want to manipulate PDFs then you probably want to use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to the end to check it and it copied the PDF file. Your code is working fine

```
        dis.close();

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\out.pdf")));
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("File size: " + read);
        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (read < bytes.length) {
            System.out.println("Could not completely read: "+file.getName());
        }
```

edit: here is my entire code, its just copied from yours. I ran it in IDE (eclipse) and entered "c:\mypdf.pdf" for the input and it copied it to out.pdf. Identical Copys. Do note that I did close both streams which I noticed you forgot to do in your code.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter File name: ");
        String str = bf.readLine();
        File file = new File(str);
        //File length
        int size = (int) file.length();
        if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("File is to larger");
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        int read = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (read < bytes.length && (numRead = dis.read(bytes, read,
                bytes.length - read)) >= 0) {
            read = read + numRead;
        }
        dis.close();

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\out.pdf")));
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("File size: " + read);

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (read < bytes.length) {
            System.out.println("Could not completely read: " + file.getName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ns47731  how did you run this?

Comment: The PDF file does not open, it says the file is damaged.